# How to correctly create a modal dialog on top of another modal dialog with PyGTK3 so that the second dialog is on top?

Tags: python, windows-10, gtk, gtk3, glade

I have a Windows-10 PyGTK3 app (python 3.8 + GTK3.24) structured as follows: it has a non-modal main window, which opens a modal dialog (A), which in turn opens another modal dialog (B).
I use glade for the layout and properties of all three windows.

On the app startup I retain the instance of the GtkWindow A as follows:

```
def __init__(self):
     self._main_window = builder.get_object("main_window")
...
def on_clicked_open_dialog_a(self, _widget):
    dlg_a = DialogA(self._main_window)
    dlg_a.run()
```

In the dialog A, I do a similar thing:

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    self._dialog = builder.get_object("dialog_a")
    self._dialog.set_transient_for(parent)
...
def on_clicked_open_dialog_b(self, _widget):
    dlg_b = DialogB(self._dialog)
    dlg_b.run()
```

And the same thing in the dialog B:

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    self._dialog = builder.get_object("dialog_b")
    self._dialog.set_transient_for(parent)
```

[This is what it is supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrkUn.png)

The problem that I am running into is that once I open the Dialog B from the Dialog A, the Dialog A ceases to behave like a proper modal dialog: if I click it, its window becomes active, even though the Dialog B is still displayed on top of it (and it can be moved and maximized/minimized, but not closed),
[like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aQyI.png)

and if I cover the app with another window and use Alt-Tab to bring the app back, the Dialog A comes on top, and I can only access the Dialog B by clicking on the Dialog A
[as appears on this diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzVXx.png)

What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it, please?

Comment: Do you have a UI file? Could you show it to us?

Comment: I would if I could. I could extract the interesting bits and post them here, if you can tell me what they are.

Comment: Just the sections for `main_window`, `dialog_a`, and `dialog_b`, like you did in your code. Be sure to include whether they are parented to/children of any widgets. Remember, you can [edit] your question to include more information. Also, have you tried calling `print(parent)` in your `__init__()` methods, to make sure that the parent widgets are what you expect them to be? This problem is rather vague; it may even have to do with what operating system you're on.